# Ruby on Rails - Create Net::HTTP request from curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

The curl that I have works and is very simple:

curl -d

> "semester=20141Summer+2013+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++&courseid=&subject=IT++INFORMATION+TECHNOLOGY&college=&campus=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C9%2CA%2CB%2CC%2CI%2CL%2CM%2CN%2CP%2CQ%2CR%2CS%2CT%2CW%2CU%2CV%2CX%2CZ&courselevel=&coursenum=&startTime=0600&endTime=2359&days=ALL&All=All+Sections"
>   http://www3.mnsu.edu/courses/selectform.asp

I'm trying to do this using Net::HTTP in ruby on rails, I have this:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://www3.mnsu.edu/courses/selectform.asp")
params = {"semester" => "20141Summer+2013+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++", 
          "subject" => "IT++INFORMATION+TECHNOLOGY",
          "campus" => "1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C9%2CA%2CB%2CC%2CI%2CL%2CM%2CN%2CP%2CQ%2CR%2CS%2CT%2CW%2CU%2CV%2CX%2CZ",
          "startTime" => "0600",
          "endTime" => "2359",
          "days" => "ALL",
          "ALL" => "All+Sections"}

#=====  FORM POST  =====#
@response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, params)
```

However, everytime it's run, it returns a "Microsoft VBScript runtime error 800a0009"
The curl never does that.

Any hints on what doesn't match up?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the remote server doesn't like Ruby's user agent. Two ways you can go about it:

**#1 Modify Net::HTTP's user agent:**

```
require 'net/http'
params = {"semester" => "20141Summer+2013+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++", 
    "subject" => "IT++INFORMATION+TECHNOLOGY",
    "campus" => "1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C9%2CA%2CB%2CC%2CI%2CL%2CM%2CN%2CP%2CQ%2CR%2CS%2CT%2CW%2CU%2CV%2CX%2CZ",
    "startTime" => "0600",
    "endTime" => "2359",
    "days" => "ALL",
    "ALL" => "All+Sections"}

uri = URI.parse("http://www3.mnsu.edu/courses/selectform.asp")
url = uri.to_s + "?" + URI.encode_www_form(params)

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
req['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22"

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http| http.request(req) }
```

This works, but gives you a "302 Object moved" message, which you would have to follow manually.

**#2 Use the [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) gem**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
@agent = Mechanize.new
@agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
page = @agent.get 'http://www3.mnsu.edu/courses/selectform.asp?semester=20141Summer+2013+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++&courseid=&subject=IT++INFORMATION+TECHNOLOGY&college=&campus=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C9%2CA%2CB%2CC%2CI%2CL%2CM%2CN%2CP%2CQ%2CR%2CS%2CT%2CW%2CU%2CV%2CX%2CZ&courselevel=&coursenum=&startTime=0600&endTime=2359&days=ALL&All=All+Sections'
```

which gets you to "MSU Class Schedule -- search for courses"

Comment: Thanks for the help.
But it doesn't look like your first provided code considers my post parameters at any point. That's why it returns the "Object moved" message.

When I include a request.set_form_data with my parameters, I get the same runtime error back :-/

Comment: I updated the code to include params with the Net::HTTP example, but the 302 redirect is still there. I can confirm it using URL-encoded GET params and `wget`, which tells me "302 Object moved. Location: Default.asp?blnNoYrtr=True". That redirection occurs even when you visit `http://www3.mnsu.edu/courses/selectform.asp` through the browser, with no params at all. This tell me the redirect is the INTENDED behavior of the site, and you have to handle the 302 yourself if you want to use Net::HTTP. Which is why I'd use Mechanize.